# APEX set value not updating

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

New to APEX. (19)

I have create a Dynamic Action to detect a change to items on and page and when this happens to update both a Last Updated By and Tags* items against the same record.

- Only using the Tags item so I can visually see it on the screen.

The Last Updated By working using:-

```
Action: SET VALUE  
Set Type: Static Assignment  
Value: &APP_USER
```

This works just fine.  However the following to update the Tags items does not update the Tags item:

```
Action: SET VALUE  
Set Type: PL/SQL Expression  
PL/SQL Expression: SYSDATE
```

It maybe obvious to you as I've said am new to this.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN6xf.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kbHY.png)
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dermx.png)

Additional notes:

1. The obvious difference between the two methods is Statis vs. a PL/SQL expression assignment.
2. The Tags is getting overridden by something, jst not the required SYSDATE.  IF there was a value in it before the update or I type into it before the update that is cleared out and it is left blank.

Maybe this is of assistance.

Comment: It works OK for me (on 18.2, though). The only difference is that my "Event" is set to "New" as 18.2 doesn't have the "Change any item" option (or I don't know how to make it visible). Does P7_TAGS have any other option that might affect its value (another dynamic action, source, default value ... *something*)? If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide username & password so that we could have a look.

Comment: Everything seems to be placed fine. Although few options you can try are 1) Set Event Scope = Dynamic 2) If previous one works, then well & good, otherwise, instead of PLSQL expression use SQL statement as(`select sysdate from dual`) with Event Scope = Dynamic
@Littlefoot "Change Any Item" is just a name for event, you can change it anytime in Identification section of Event. By default, event name is "New".

Comment: @Arif: ah! Silly me! Got it, thank you. "New" ... bah.

Comment: Hello FlintF, welcome to Apex. The best practice to manage audit columns like record creation date and update date is to use a database trigger rather than an item in the form. Main reason: The last update date recorded in the form will never be the time the database record is updated. In your case there could even be a significant difference. It is also extremely easy to implement, there is no work needed in the application.

Comment: ... continued... 
The apex team uses this architecture as well. You can see how these triggers are created by installing any of the productivity apps and then checking any trigger with the "_BIU" extension. (BIU stands for "Before Insert or Update")

Comment: Koen - thank you, yes I fully understand that and will be implementing auditing via DB triggers mostly.  This example is get a feel of how things work with DA as they seems very powerful going forward

Comment: Ok - I have made the following progress. I have found that if I make a change in one item and go directly another item or to the Apply Changes button then Only the LAST_UPDATED_BY gets changed. However if I make a change and move to another item via a tab then Both get updated?  The tab is causing both items to update?

Comment: @GoranKutlaca thanks, I'll need to learn more about how to do the formatting!   Can you show me what you typed in to get the above format?

Comment: @FlintF sure, for this specific formatting of inline text I separated the text in it's own paragraph and then used 4 empty spaces before every line. You can see all the formatting options and descriptions here: <https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help>

Comment: So...  the following. The two dynamic actions do fire correctly and populate their respective items.  However when they are an SQL Expression (also tried function) then unless you have entered another item before hitting the *Apply Changes* button then the value is not stored in the database (session).  Do I need to do something else to ensure the session is updated?

Comment: What type of item is P7_TAGS?

Comment: It is a text item that I populate with a date.  I was playing around with user and last updated date type population.  Oct 3 comment sort of defines where I got too.  I have kept moving forward and I needed to make progress.